# Tree command on OS X Bash

Tags: bash, macos, tree, homebrew

**OS:** MacOS Mojave 10.14.6 **Shell:** Bash 5.0.11 (Homebrew's Bash)

I installed the tree formula from [homebrew](/questions/tagged/homebrew), but am having difficulty in getting it to output in the colors that I want.

The system default `$LSCOLORS` for mac is `LSCOLORS=exfxcxdxbxegedabagacad`.  In my .bash_profile, mine is set to `LSCOLORS=gxcxdxdxbxxxxxbxbxgxgx`.  I also have `CLICOLOR=1` set.

If I leave my `.bash_profile` like this and run `ls`, the output shows in the colors I want.  However, when I run `tree`, the output shows the system default colorization.

I have tried changing `$LSCOLORS` to `$LS_COLORS`, because that is what the man page for tree suggests.  The "ls" command still shows the correct colors, but this results in tree printing everything in default colors (no colorization at all).  The same goes when `$TREE_COLORS` is set.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not only do BSD and GNU `ls` use different environment variables, but the *value* of those variables have different formats. You can't simply use the same value for both `LSCOLORS` and `LS_COLORS`.

Comment: You should use (after installing, if necessary) `dircolors` to generate the appropriate value of `LS_COLORS`.

Comment: [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) provides `gdircolors`. I'm fairly certain`dircolors` doesn't exist on macOS.

Comment: After adding it to your `.bash_profile` presumably you are creating a new session for the changes to be effective?

Comment: This solved it! Thank you.  I exported gdircolors to a file .dircolors which I saved in my $USER folder, made the modifications there, and sourced it.

Comment: @RobC Neither does `tree` until you install it; `dircolors` has to be installed as well. HomeBrew's version of coreutils prefixes everything with a `g` to avoid conflicting with the versions of `ls`, etc already installed, though `gdircolors` seems to merely be an attempt at uniformity.

Answer (score 5):

On OS X, the `$LSCOLORS` variable defines the colored output for the `ls` command.  Because `tree` isn't a native command for OS X, it looks for the GNU variables and their associated formats to determine what color to use.  If these aren't set, it will use the system defaults.

If you don't have GNU commands installed, you can get them from homebrew by running:

```sh
brew install coreutils
```

In order to avoid conflicts with OS X commands, all GNU commands are installed prefixed with a `g`.  So entering `ls` would run the OS X version of the `ls` command, while entering `gls` runs the GNU version of the `ls` command.

Once the GNU commands are installed, you have to set your color variables in the way that a Linux system would understand.  Running the command `dircolors` on a GNU shell gives you the default value for the `$LS_COLORS` variable.  So because all commands are installed prefixed with a `g`, run `gdircolors`.  Copy the output into your `.bash_profile`, and modify colors as desired.

This is a really in depth guide about what each of the keys means, and what codes correspond to which colors: http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/2008/04/11/configuring-ls_colors The system also provides a guide, although it is less in depth.  To see this, run `gdircolors -p`.

Now, I have both variables defined in my `.bash_profile`.

```sh
export CLICOLOR=1 
export LSCOLORS=gxcxdxdxbxxxxxbxbxgxgx
```

This first enables colored output, then defines the colors that the OS X version of the `ls` command uses.

```sh
LS_COLORS='rs=0:di=36:ln=32:mh=00:pi=33:so=33:do=33:bd=00:cd=00:or=05;36:mi=04;93:su=31:sg=31:ca=00:tw=36:ow=36:st=36:ex=031:*.tar=00:*.tgz=00:*.arc=00:*.arj=00:*.taz=00:*.lha=00:*.lz4=00:*.lzh=00:*.lzma=00:*.tlz=00:*.txz=00:*.tzo=00:*.t7z=00:*.zip=00:*.z=00:*.dz=00:*.gz=00:*.lrz=00:*.lz=00:*.lzo=00:*.xz=00:*.zst=00:*.tzst=00:*.bz2=00:*.bz=00:*.tbz=00:*.tbz2=00:*.tz=00:*.deb=00:*.rpm=00:*.jar=00:*.war=00:*.ear=00:*.sar=00:*.rar=00:*.alz=00:*.ace=00:*.zoo=00:*.cpio=00:*.7z=00:*.rz=00:*.cab=00:*.wim=00:*.swm=00:*.dwm=00:*.esd=00:*.jpg=00:*.jpeg=00:*.mjpg=00:*.mjpeg=00:*.gif=00:*.bmp=00:*.pbm=00:*.pgm=00:*.ppm=00:*.tga=00:*.xbm=00:*.xpm=00:*.tif=00:*.tiff=00:*.png=00:*.svg=00:*.svgz=00:*.mng=00:*.pcx=00:*.mov=00:*.mpg=00:*.mpeg=00:*.m2v=00:*.mkv=00:*.webm=00:*.ogm=00:*.mp4=00:*.m4v=00:*.mp4v=00:*.vob=00:*.qt=00:*.nuv=00:*.wmv=00:*.asf=00:*.rm=00:*.rmvb=00:*.flc=00:*.avi=00:*.fli=00:*.flv=00:*.gl=00:*.dl=00:*.xcf=00:*.xwd=00:*.yuv=00:*.cgm=00:*.emf=00:*.ogv=00:*.ogx=00:*.aac=00:*.au=00:*.flac=00:*.m4a=00:*.mid=00:*.midi=00:*.mka=00:*.mp3=00:*.mpc=00:*.ogg=00:*.ra=00:*.wav=00:*.oga=00:*.opus=00:*.spx=00:*.xspf=00:';

export LS_COLORS
```

This defines the colors that the GNU version of the `ls` command uses.  This is also the color scheme that the `tree` command uses (and I'm guessing all other GNU commands).

It is also possible to store these variables in a file, such as `.dircolors` and simply add the following line to your `.bash_profile` instead:

```sh
source '/path/.dircolors'
```

In the above, make sure to substitute `path` with the path to the `.dircolors` file. However, I prefer to keep everything neatly in one place, namely my `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 0):

The problems stem from GNU's `tree` not playing well with the BSD-based macOS's color environment variables, as explained in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59431942/1562596).

I only managed to get this working by forcing colors with `tree -C`.

A drawback with a simple alias as `alias tree='tree -C'` is that this will print ANSI color codes also when the output is sent to something else than a terminal, e.g. when redirecting to a file: `tree > file.txt`. To see the messy output, try with e.g. `tree -C | cat -v`.

I get around this by using a custom function instead of an alias.

In `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc`:

```bash
function tree() {
  local treeArgs=(-I __pycache__)    # list any desired default arguments
  _isTerminal() { [[ -t 1 ]]; }
  _isTerminal && treeArgs+=(-C)      # conditionally force color
  command tree "${treeArgs[@]}" "$@" # run the command
  unset -f _isTerminal
}
```

Tested with `bash 5.1` and `zsh 5.8.1`.